# How do I get notified when a response is finished when using `hapi`?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm trying to migrate a bit of middleware from `express` to `hapi`. Here's the thing in `express`:

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express()

server.use(function (req, res, next) {
  const start = Date.now()
  res.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('Timestamp', Date.now() - start)
  })

  next()
})

//...
```

When using `hapi`, I can't find a good way of getting notified when the response finishes within the same closure, so that I can use the initial data I set up when the request started...

The closest I've got is this:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi')
const server = new Hapi.Server()

server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, reply) => {
  const start = Date.now()
  request.response.once('finish', () => {
    console.log('Timestamp', Date.now() - start)
  })

  return reply.continue()
})

// ...
```

But error responses seem to have `request.response` set to `null`, so I can't add listeners to it.

Suggestions?

Comment: this is the first result in google when you search for hapi finish

Answer (score 0):

```
 server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, reply) {
    request.response.once('finish', function () {    

    });   
    reply.continue(); 
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what my first attempt was (see original question), but this doesn't work for error responses, as `request.response` is set to `null`.

Comment: @DanielPerezAlvarez this should work. I use a similar setup to check for Mongo specific errors with `if (request.response instanceof Error)...`. Perhaps explore how you are passing errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `request.raw.req`'s `end` event:

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, reply) => {

    request.raw.req.once('end', () => console.log('DONE!!!'));
    return reply.continue();
});
```

Comment: Yup, although some things behave weirdly, like the `statusCode` of the response not matching what I set when calling `reply().code(...)`. Super weird.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.response.events.once('finish', () => console.log('DONE!!!'));
```

Comment: This apply for Hapi version >= 17

Comment: Would you like to augment your code only answer with some explanation? Even what you write in your comment on your own answer (which should be part of the answer itself) is not providing any insight.

Comment: Consider applying the cool things described here, to improve the readability of your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help